# Intersection with rays in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

can anyone tell me how to calculate intersections of rays and objects in TikZ? Normally the syntax is `intersection of p1--p2 and p3--p4`, but I would like to intersect the line segment from p1 to p2 with a ray starting at p3 and going into a direction e. Is that possible with TikZ?

Comment: What is `e` in TikZ object terms?  A coordinate that you're treating like a vector?

Comment: I think this should be a feature request!

Comment: Using elementary linear algebra you can get a closed formula for the intersection coordinates. This should be somehow implemented in a command which calculates intersections of rays...

Answer (score 8):

You could cheat by intersecting the line p1 to p2 (called `AB` in the code sample below) with an "infinitely long" (e.g. one metre...) path that's not drawn. You have to reset the bounding box after defining the "ray", because otherwise your `tikzpicture` will too big.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % Only used for showing the bounding box
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\coordinate (C) at (1,1);
\path [name path=Cray] 
  \foreach \n in {-45,-40,...,45}{ (C) -- +(\n:100cm) };
\pgfresetboundingbox

\draw [name path=AB] (3,-2) .. controls(10,0) and (8,5) .. (8,5);
\draw [red,name intersections={of=AB and Cray,sort by=AB,total=\t}] 
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\t} { (C) -- (intersection-\i) };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: rays intersecting a line in tikz]

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to create a point `p4alt` at some standard distance, say `1cm`, from `p3` and then use `p3--p4alt` in your intersection specification; no need to draw the point `p4alt` itself. If, say, `e` is at 115 degrees, you would use `\draw (p3) ++(115:1cm) coordinate (p4alt) ;` to set up the ray from `p3`.